# Отключение бота от голосового канала при отсутствии подключённых

Tags: javascript, discord

Я создаю музыкального бота для дискорда. Как мне узнать когда участник отключается от канала, проверить если есть кто в нём, если нету то отключиться ?

Моя неудачная попытка, пытался заставить работать это, но у меня не вышло.

```
sdr.on('voiceStateUpdate', (message, oldState, newState) => {
  let voicebotcon = message.guild.voice.connection;
  if(!voicebotcon) return;
  let voicememcon = message.members.voice.channel;
  if(!voicememcon) return;
  if(voicememcon === voicebotcon) {
    if(oldState) {
      voicememcon.leave()
      message.channel.send('Бот отключился от канала')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Приведите свои попытки написания кода. Покажите что не получается. Мы не будем работать за Вас.

Comment: Простите, я добавил код, это единственный уцелевшая моя попытка, остальные я стёр

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите, тут достаточно нелепая ошибка. Я не хочу в Вас тыкать пальцем, просто хочу расставить все точки над i.

Итак, начнем с азов: **Что такое событие voiceStateUpdate**?

Оно происходит, когда сменилось состояние пользователя в **голосовом канале** (заглушение, включение демонстрации, и т.п.), что мы можем понять даже по его названию. При данном событии нам передается всего два значения, это **предыдущее состояние** и **текущее состояние**.

Итак, **в чем суть ошибки?**

Здесь все довольно однозначно: откуда взялось значение `message`, непонятно (на этом момент не стоит бегом бежать все исправлять, дочитайте, пожалуйста), ведь мы имеем всего два значения: предыдущее и текущее состояние.

**Как же не допускать таких ошибок?**

Рекомендую подробно изучить события и документацию в целом библиотеки `discord.js` - [discord.js.org](https://discord.js.org).

Итак, исправленный код, с комментариями и рекомендациями:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {
    // Если инициатор события - бот, игнорируем, во избежание перезаходов
    if (newState.id === client.user.id) return;
    // Если бот не в канале - прерываем дальнейшее выполнение
    if (!newState.guild.me.voice.channelID) return;
    // Если пользователь зашел в канал - прерываем
    if (!oldState.channelID) return;
    // Если бота нет в канале - прерываем
    if (oldState.channelID !== newState.guild.me.voice.channelID) return;
    // Определяем, вышел ли пользователь из канала. Если нет - прерываем
    if (newState.channelID) return;
    // Определяем значение гильдии, для удобности (и понятности)
    let guild = newState.guild;
    // Получаем объект канала
    let channel = guild.channels.resolve(oldState.channelID);
    // Если в канале есть кто-то кроме бота - прерываем
    if (channel.members.size > 1) return;
    // Выходим из канала и пишем сообщение
    await guild.me.voice.setChannel(null);
    return await guild.channels.resolve('ID Чата').send(`Я вышел из канала \`${channel.name}\` из-за неактивности`);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое